# How can I display storage units ( ex. KB, GB ) on y-axis in Plotly - Python

Tags: plotly-python

I have a graph for monitoring memory statistics over time.
Generated via the following python snippet.

```
data = {"Time": x, "Memory": sizes}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="Time",
    y="Memory",
    title="Dir {0}".format(dir_name),
    
)
fig.show()
```

As you can see in the attached image GB are shown as billions of numbers and it's divided by 1000 instead of 1024.

I want to have a dynamic extension according to the actual size, and have a correct extension ( in this case GB ).

[image]

Thanks.